# Why can't I perform a simple count in a subquery?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to write a simple query that fetches all the columns of a specific table, but also adds a count of rows from a related table.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
   todos.*, 
   (SELECT COUNT(assets.*) FROM assets WHERE assets.parent_id = todos._id) AS asset_count 
FROM todos
```

Here is the error:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "*": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT todos.*, (SELECT COUNT(assets.*) FROM assets WHERE assets.parent_id = todos._id) AS asset_count FROM todos
```

Comment: heh ... this is a normal way: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/10326/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replace `COUNT(assets.*)` for `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(assets._id)`

my second suggestion, try running the inside select like a single one

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM assets WHERE assets.parent_id = 1 <-- any _id you have
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Thank you very much Juan Carlos!